# Scrolltop safari bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos, safari

I´m using Safari 6.0.2 on mac.

This is the [website:](http://codekunstler.com/test/danirubio/)

I have a problem that only happens in safari with the `scrolltop` .

If I click on a project and then click on the image to show the next one, the viewport stays the same on chrome and firefox, but on safari the page jumps to top.

Try clicking on safari on the project **Fusteria Ollé**, then on it´s image and you´ll see the problem.

This is my code:

```
    function project_display(that){
        $('.info_content').hide();
        var $submenu = $(that).next('.project'),
        viz = $submenu.is(":visible");
        if (!viz) {
            $(that).addClass('active');
            $(that).next().find('.slider').show();
            $(that).next('.project').slideDown(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top -50
                }, 300);
            });
        }
    };
```

Any ideas what is wrong on safari?

**Safari:**
[image]

**Chrome/firefox:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug a while ago, which is already fixed. Chrome updates more often his browser, so it has already disappeared there.

See also http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/139669 for the bugfix.

Yes, it was fixed already a four months ago, but Apple is usually slow with updating Safari when there's no real security issue. You may want to test with the actual nightly Webkit: http://nightly.webkit.org/